# has anyone used simile timeline with large amounts of data

Tags: performance, scaling, timeline, simile

i am using this [simile timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) with large amounts of data and i keep getting firefox popping up saying "a script has appeared to no longer be running, do you want to kill it"?  is there a limit to the amount of json you can send back to it.  I have about 1000 different timeline points with dates, descriptions, etc.

Comment: Is there anything related to JSON that limits time or size?  I can think of a few instances (unrelated to JSON) that required increasing the time allowed to process before timing out.
Does the timeout occur in other browsers?

Comment: Can you include more information about your current program. Why you don't use / can't use paging of data? Why do you need transfer large amounts of data inside of web browser. No user are able read / modify large amounts of data at once.

Comment: @Oleg - i dont think simile supports paging of data . .

Comment: Nevertheless, could you post a little more information about you application? Do application a lot of scientific calculation or database access or ... There are no large amounts of data in general. Probably if you change a little the problem statement, your real problem can be solved more effectively. If you use HTTP as a communication interface for example, we don't need speak about performance in firefox or other web browsers.

Comment: @ Oleg - there is no complicated logic on the serverside.  items are retrieved from a db and sent down in json format to client.  There is just a lot of data points as mentioned. JSON IS going over http.  i dont understand what you are talking about

Comment: Could you use lazy loading?  http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/wiki/Timeline_LoadEventsDynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will always happen if your script takes longer to process the data than the limit in Firefox (you can change the default, but it'll still affect your other users).

Timeline allows you to reduce that by reducing the number of points loaded to only the ones needed to show. Use `addOnScrollListener` to reload the data in the band so that the number of datapoints loaded is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the load on the browser is to use new Date() objects instead of date strings in the event data, thus obviating the need for the browser to parse the dates.

`{"events":
    [{title : "an event", start : new Date(1999,4,27), description : "event description"},
    {title : "another event", start : new Date(1999,5,7), description : "another event"}]
    }`

see the simile wiki on: [Date_Time_Formats](http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_EventSources#Date_Time_Formats)